# unable to add new item in array using useState,it get overwrite value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to save values in an array whenever the user clicks on the save button, I'm working with API which give the data for the recipe

Home.js (component calling API and passing props to Recipe component )

```
recipes.map((recipe)=>(
           <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4} container
           direction="row"
           justify="space-around"
           alignItems="center"
          >
           <*Recipe*
           main={recipe}
           key={recipe.recipe.label}
           title={recipe.recipe.label}
           calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
           image={recipe.recipe.image}
           ingredients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
           healthLabels={recipe.recipe.healthLabels})
```

(i'm trying to do whenever the user click on BookmarkIcon, handleSave function add all the data (coming as a props from Home.js) into separate index but problem is i have to click to two time to add into array but after clicking on the new item previos lost pls suggest me what is the right approach)

Recipe.js:-

```
const [Save, setSave] = useState([{id:1,item:{one:1,two:2}}]);

<IconButton  onClick={handleSave}>
          <BookmarkIcon/>
</IconButton>

const handleSave= ()=>{
         const length=Save.length
         const data=  main.recipe
          setSave((pre)=>[...pre,{id:length+1,item:{data}}])
          // console.log("Save_item",Save)
          // console.log("main_item",main.recipe)
          console.log("inner",Save)
    }
```

Comment: What is this `[{id:1,item:{one:1,two:2}}]`? you want to overwrite the whole data or you want the new data to be saved in `Save`?

Comment: no, it is just for reference I want to add new data on a new index I'm thinking that data is coming from Home.js and I want to add data of a particular item in the array whenever i click to button

Comment: then you could do like this ` setSave([...Save,...data.map((datat,id)=>({id : id, data : data}))])`